# verbs of creation and a resultative adjectival

Tags: prepositions, verbs, resultative

I'm wondering whether verbs of creation, such as *build*, *construct*, and *produce*, can be followed by an object and then an adjectival denoting the result, with the pattern of "shoot him dead."

Are the following sentences correct?

> 1. John built my garage rather small/smaller than I had expected.

> 2. Victor Frankenstein constructed his monster gigantic.

If the above are incorrect, what about the following?

> 3. John built the garage in my designated size.

> 4. Victor Frankenstein constructed his monster in a gigantic size.

Comment: I'm sure there's a grammatical term for the difference between *He built the wall **quicker** [than expected]* and *He built it **taller*** - where the adverbial element could modify either the *[subject +] **verb***, or the ***object***. And where only ***pragmatics / semantics*** tells you how to interpret it.

Comment: You can say simply "Build it big!", so you can do that with "build".  
 I can't think of an example off-hand for "construct" or "produce".  
 Your second sentence doesn't sound quite right to me. 3 and 4 have preposition phrases that seem like adverbs, not adjectives.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Does #4 sound odd to you?

Comment: @Apollyon It's grammatical,if you've decided to use the verb "construct". I might have said "VF made his monster gigantic."